# emacs-like mark selection in textmate

Tags: textmate

I used emacs for years before being convinced to switch over to textmate. I am mostly happy with the move but really, really miss the ability to select text by setting a mark and then moving the cursor; using shift + arrow just doesn't cut it for me. I have tried a couple bindings based on some out-dated blog posts out there but just can't figure it out!

Anybody know of a bundle or binding that will help me get this functionality?

Comment: Do you mean like Emacs `C-SPACE` Set beginning mark?

Comment: @Slomojo Yup, that is exactly what I am talking about. Any ideas?

Comment: aside from going back to Emacs?

Comment: ha, don't think I have not considered it. However, the cost/benefit is such I am sticking with textmate. If it were not for this 1 issue, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do that in TextMate. It has bookmarks, used for navigation, but nothing like what you describe.

If I remember correctly, placing the caret somewhere and extending the selection with <kbd>⇧</kbd> + arrows is the only practical way to select stuff in TextMate.

Like in all Mac OS X applications you can accelerate the process by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd> and go word by word.

There are 3 special shortcuts you might find useful but I don't think they will solve your problem:

- <kbd>^</kbd> + `W` to select the current Word
- <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> + `L` to select the current Line
- <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> + `B` to select between enclosing pairs

A [bundle](https://github.com/subtleGradient/SelectStuff.tmbundle) I've used for some time (but under a different name, I think) proposes scope-oriented selection. I remember it being quite useful at times but also a bit buggy.

Comment: Hey @romainl, thanks for the answer. What you propose is close and is both a little bit of what I currently do with a couple helpful tips, but it is not what I am looking for. But again, thanks for the comment.

Comment: I've used TextMate for years but I've never seen such a feature, the [TextMate book](http://pragprog.com/press_releases/textmate) doesn't even mention something remotely like it. My guess is that either it's not possible or it has never been done. By the why did you switch? I've switched about a year ago from TM to Vim and now, TextMate feels like TextEdit to me.

Comment: My experience is similar to romainl, except I switched to Emacs for my general purpose editor.